# How do I show counts for combinations of categories?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a `ProdID` column, followed by a set of taxonomies and terms.  For a trivial example:

```
ProdID  |  Type  |  Size  |  Color  |  Flavor  |  ...
10231   |  A     |  LG    |  GREY   |  BAD     |  ...
```

There are 73 total terms split across 12 taxonomies.

The table has around 43,000 entries.

Users are displayed a Taxonomy filter, where they can select various combinations of taxonomies and terms to display (similar to search results on Amazon or Zappos).

The client wants to have a products count next to each term in the list, that shows how many results they will receive, if they add that term to their current selections.

This is the same functionality seen on zappos, when you begin to browse products.  You are shown a count next to each "category" that is the number of results you will see, if you click it. (e.g. http://www.zappos.com/womens-casual-shoes~94 - in the sidebar section for "categories", there is a count next to each term)

The way I see it, calculating number of potential results seems to be a roughly equivalent problem to getting those results, computationally, so running 73 complex SQL queries on every page load seems like a poor (aka slow) choice.

Alternatively, pre-calculating the counts or results for every possible filter selection seems like a fools errand (if my math is correct, there are 2^73 possible distinct subsets, which, if each query took 1ms to run, would take 3e11 years to complete)

So, I assume there is either a better data-structure to get this count from, or the results are being calculated on the fly, and each request is cached, so that common requests run faster.

Is there a better data-structure, that can yield these counts faster?

Comment: Can you show us what is your desire result. Because in amazon they only show the total for one category and that is easy to do http://i.stack.imgur.com/e5cIN.png

Comment: @juan-carlos-oropeza check out http://www.zappos.com/womens-casual-shoes~94  each of the sidebar categories shows count next to name

Comment: I dont see the problem, they have to run a separated query for each category every time you change a filter parameter. Why you say is a complex query?

Answer (score 1):

Your original table will be `T` and you create and unpivot table `U`.

```
ProdID  |  Filter  |  Value 
10231   |  Type    |  A
10231   |  Size    |  LG
10231   |  Color   |  Gray
10231   |  Flavor  |  Bad
```

Then you calculate each taxonomies totals

```
SELECT Filter, Value, Count(*)
FROM U
WHERE U.ProdID IN (SELECT T.ProdID
                   FROM T
                   WHERE color = @color  -- need build this filter dinamic.
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that they are doing a lot of this in memory, possibly not even with a SQL solution. Amazon uses a variety of solutions to accommodate the size of data and throughput that they need to handle and have even started marketing some of their technology with their Amazon Web Services.

That said, for a SQL solution... assuming that the user has already selected the color "Yellow", you should be able to do the following for each of your taxonomies.

```
SELECT
    type, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    Products
WHERE
    color = 'YELLOW'
```

You would then have to run that 12 times to fill in your sidebar. As additional filter criteria is selected you could then adjust your `WHERE` clause appropriately.

You could also wait until your user has selected some amount of minimal search criteria, put everything into memory, then calculate your counts from that as the user selects and deselects different criteria. Depending on the number of products that you have and the amount of traffic that the website see, this might be faster.